# Samba authentication with another samba

Tags: authentication, samba

I have a samba share with build-in authentication (smbpasswd).

No any central auth (ldap, ad , radius ) in this network.

My task is, start another samba server on second hosts with same user/pass for shares.

Is it possible that samba2 use auth with samba1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be setting up ldap or some other centralized user storage. You could use an easy solution like ClearOS, Zentyal or something similar. But if you would really like to just copy them over you could create a cronjob to copy them to the other server for example very hour:

```
pdbedit -e tdbsam:backup.tdbsam
```

Would export the accounts to the backup.tdbsam file and then you would scp over this file and use pdbedit -i to import them into samba.